# internet connection is suspended whenever I run an MS Access query

Tags: internet-connection, microsoft-access

Whenever I run a query in Access 2010, I can't use the internet.  My pages won't load until the query finishes and my downloads hang.  Anybody know why that is and how it can be corrected?

Comment: is the query actually executing on your box, or is it using a network resource like a linked table?

Comment: Need more details. Can you do anything else why the query is running? Is the query local (i.e. not on a remote SQL server or other database). Is your CPU utilization at 100% during the query? Is it a query of a particular type, or literally any query can cause this? Provide, if you can, the simplest query that reproduces it.

Comment: @FrankThomas The db is on a network, but the table data is within the db.

Comment: @Argonauts The cpu utilization is under 10%.  The network utilization goes from 0 to ~60% though; maybe it's just slowing my connection way down running a query through a large db on a network.  I'll try saving it locally.

Comment: It doesn't impact at all when I save the db locally; I guess running a query when the db is on the network dominates my connection.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. if the DB was hosted remotely on a database server  (like with linked tables) then the CPU would happen on the server, and the only network transfer would be the query text and the result set, but locally querying a database file on a network share, the entire database must be copied to temporary storage and it may happen more than once as the query's expression tree is built and executed.